# Using pip to install single-file python modules

Tags: python, pip

I'm wondering if there's a way to "install" single-file python modules using pip (i.e. just have pip download the specified version of the file and copy it to site-packages).

I have a Django project that uses several 3rd-party modules which aren't proper distributions (django-thumbs and a couple others) and I want to `pip freeze` everything so the project can be easily installed elsewhere.  I've tried just doing

`pip install git+https://github.com/path/to/file.git`

(and tried with the -e tag too) but pip complains that there's no setup.py file.

Edit: I should have mentioned - the reason I want to do this is so I can include the required module in a requirements.txt file, to make setting up the project on a new machine or new virtualenv easier.

Answer (score 2):

`pip` requires a valid setup.py to install a python package. By definition every python package has a setup.py... What you are trying to install isn't a package but rather a single file module... what's wrong with doing something like:

```
git clone git+https://github.com/path/to/file.git /path/to/python/install/lib
```

I don't quite understand the logic behind wanting to install something that isn't a package with a package manager...

Comment: I was just curious if I could condense the entire project into a single requirements file that could be pip installed with one command.    Having to `git clone` each module individually is somewhat less elegant.  (I recently tried to get someone else set up with the project on his computer and he ran into a bunch of problems, which is what motivated the question)

Comment: setup from setuptools allows users to specify single py file dependencies (http://peak.telecommunity.com/DevCenter/setuptools#dependencies-that-aren-t-in-pypi), so pip should provide this in order to be compliant with setup interface.

Moreover, single py file modules are quite flexible and comfortable.